# Can't able to track table row using ng-repeat-start(ngAnimate) to expand

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-animate

I want to track the expanded row and save that form with city and work details, the problem is while clicking on the particular row it's expanding with form but I can't able to track that row...

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('itemsController', function( $scope ) {

$scope.divisions    = [{id:12, div_name:' city1'},
                      {id:13, div_name:' city2'},
                      {id:14, div_name:' city3'}];

$scope.works        =[{wid:111, w_name:'work1'},
                     {wid:222, w_name:'work2'},
                     {wid:333, w_name:'work3'}];
});
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="itemsController" class="box">

<table border="1">
    <tbody ng-repeat-start="division in divisions">
        <td>
            {{division.div_name}}
            <em>{{expanded}}</em>
        </td>
        <td>Values: {{divisions.length}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="expanded = !expanded">
                Expand
            </button>
        </td>
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-repeat-end ng-show="expanded">
        <td colspan="3">

             <select ng-model="result.division.tt">
               <option value='01'>tt1..........</option>
               <option value='02'>tt2..........</option>
             </select><br/><br/>
                <ul ng-repeat="work in works">
                   {{work.w_name}}  <input type=text />                                
                </ul><br/><br/>
                 <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>{{result |json}}
```

link - http://jsfiddle.net/raju10281/eqk6attx/18/

Thank You in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/h7k6j5kg/6/). You should create object(`ng-init='data={}'`) for each `ng-repeat`. It  will present content of each form, then you can use it inside your controller(`ng-click="save(division, data)"`) with appropriate `division`:

```
<tbody ng-repeat-end ng-show="expanded" ng-init='data={id:division.id,div_name:division.div_name,works:[]}'>
    <td colspan="3">

         <select ng-model="data.tt">
           <option value='01'>tt1..........</option>
           <option value='02'>tt2..........</option>
         </select><br/><br/>
            <ul ng-repeat="work in works" ng-init='data.works[$index]={wid:work.wid,w_name:work.w_name}'>
               {{work.w_name}}  <input type=text ng-model='data.works[$index].input' />
            </ul><br/><br/>
            <button ng-click="save(division, data)">save</button>
    </td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: hi @Slava Utesinov , but how do i catch both entity id and name of each fields and division name and id too

Comment: You can get all of them inside `save` method: `division.id`, `division.div_name`, `data.work1`, `data.work2`, `data.work3`, `data.tt`.

Comment: `data` will look like `{'111': 'a', '222': 'b', '333': 'c', 'tt': '01'}`, where numeric property names are   `wid`s and `tt` is `'01'`

Comment: how do it get it in the below json format                                                                           
[{id:12, div_name:'city1',
  tt:01,
 [{wid:111, w_name:'work1', input:'a' },
  {wid:222, w_name:'work2', input:'b' },
  {wid:333, w_name:'work3', input:'c' } ] ;
 }];

Comment: @RajuSah, look at updated answer where `data` looks like `{ "id": 12, "div_name": " city1", "works": [ { "wid": 111, "w_name": "work1", "input": "1" }, { "wid": 222, "w_name": "work2", "input": "2" }, { "wid": 333, "w_name": "work3", "input": "3" } ] } `

Comment: great! @slava utesinov, i have added one more nested ng-repeat under work i.e subwork but i can't able to catch subwork data, can you please check   http://jsfiddle.net/raju10281/h7k6j5kg/7/

Comment: I think you should create another question for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Slava Utesinov